# Multiple users login shows fail test in JMeter?

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, jmeter-3.2

In Jmeter I created 7 Threads to login multiple users.I put 7 usernames and 7 passwords in csv file then I created CSV Data set config in JMeter and it works well but when I start to test it shows fail 7 threads pls see the image.

[image: CSV Data Config]

[image: HTTP Request with parameters]

[image: Result tree shows fail]

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you need to perform [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) of the `SessionId` parameter, like:

1. Add a relevant [Post-Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) as a child of the first request (the recommended one for HTML response type is [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)) and configure it to fetch `SessionId` value from the previous response
2. Substitute recorded value of `467132418` with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) originating form the Post-Processor in the subsequent request
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 for all samplers where `SessionId` is being used

Comment: yeah youre right but how to do that..can u give me example?